# HTML within page link

Tags: html, css

I'm aware that you can use html anchors to link to parts of a certain page.
However, I can't get it to work for the css template I currently have.
The navigation in the format provided works, but within a subsection of the page, the #name link stops working. I tried putting the id within the header, an  tag and the panel id, but none of it works. Here is the source

view-source:http://matthewpiatetsky.com/cs103/

specifically the link to #p1 doesn't work

Comment: the JavaScript you have changes the behavior of the page.  Disable JavaScript and you can see the #tag in the URL will link to the correct spot in the page.  To get it to link with the JavaScript in place you will need to add a piece of script that checks for the # in the URL and triggers the appropriate JavaScript action.

Comment: i see. thank you! i don't understand JavaScript very well yet, so I'm temporarily creating links to static pages and I'll try to implement it correctly later.